# Zoom and center a Google Map according to its markers (JavaScript API V3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I think the title is enough, I don't even see how to do this for the V2 and V1 API :/

Thanks :)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

As the other answers suggested, the [`fitBounds()`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) method should do the trick.

Consider the following example, which will generate 10 random points on the North East USA, and applies the `fitBounds()` method:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps LatLngBounds.extend() Demo</title> 
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
           type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
   });

   var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

   var randomPoint, i;

   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     // Generate 10 random points within North East USA
     randomPoint = new google.maps.LatLng( 39.00 + (Math.random() - 0.5) * 20, 
                                          -77.00 + (Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

     // Draw a marker for each random point
     new google.maps.Marker({
       position: randomPoint, 
       map: map
     });

     // Extend markerBounds with each random point.
     markerBounds.extend(randomPoint);
   }

   // At the end markerBounds will be the smallest bounding box to contain
   // our 10 random points

   // Finally we can call the Map.fitBounds() method to set the map to fit
   // our markerBounds
   map.fitBounds(markerBounds);

   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Refreshing this example many times, no marker ever goes outside the viewport:

[image: fitBounds demo]

Comment: Thanks to all of you, that was exactlly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 8):

Here is the way:

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);
map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
```

bounds is an array of the coordinates (markers). Every time when you place marker do something like:

```
bounds.extend(currLatLng);
```

Comment: I do not think setCenter is necessary after fitBounds

Answer (score 1):

**Center Zoom Depends On Single Marker**

```
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(38.8106813,-89.9600172);
var map;
var marker;
var mapProp;
function initialize()
{
    mapProp = {
        center:myCenter,
        zoom:8,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapProp);

    marker=new google.maps.Marker({
        position:myCenter,
        animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
        title:"400 St. Louis Street Edwardsville, IL 62025"
    });

    marker.setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "zoom_changed", function() {
        map.setCenter(myCenter);
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Computing the right zoom to show all your markers isn't trivial. But there's a function for that: `GMap.fitBounds()` - you define a bound (for example, the most extreme points of all your marker coordinates) and it sets the map accordingly. See e.g. [fitbounds() in Google maps api V3 does not fit bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494756/fitbounds-in-google-maps-api-v3-does-not-fit-bounds) (the answer!) for a good example.