# Set proper zoom level on google maps

Tags: google-maps, zooming, google-maps-markers

in my web app I've got a google map used to display some locations on it. Each of these locations is stored in a db and shown on the map. 
I need to set the map zoom level so that all the markers are included in the area shown by the map. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) class and then as you add each location/marker to your map you use the `extend(point:LatLng)` method to extend the bound by the markers LatLng coordinate. When you're done adding markers and extending the LatLngBounds you use the [Map class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) methods `fitBounds(bounds:LatLngBounds)` or `panToBounds(latLngBounds:LatLngBounds)` to zoom and move the viewport to fit the bound.

Daniel Vassallo provides a nice code example of all of this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3521067/881551

Answer (score 1):

The zoom level range from 0 to 21
For your case you probably want to set the value to lower as possible probably about 8 or 9.
You may see below example here:
where it display 10 locations together into one google map.

http://www.webkeet.com/webtutorials/tabid/78/id/53/using-reverse-geocoding-latitude-and-longitude-and-address-geocoding-to-display-google-map.aspx