# Java/Javascript Calculate fitbounds SW/NE with user location in center

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude, delta

What I am trying to do is trying to calculate SW, NE of given locations and then delta with user's centre location. which will result to fitbounds all locations and user's location in centre.

but unfortunaly it is not working any one quick suggestion ?

```
public void calculateMapFitBounds(GeoLocation userLocation, List<GeoLocation > contents, Map<String, GeoLocation> latlngBounds){

        //SW
        double minLat = userLocation.getLatitude();
        double minLng = userLocation.getLongitude();

        //NE
        double maxLat = -9999;
        double maxLng = -9999;

        for(GeoLocation content: contents){

            /*
             * Populating Top left cordinate (SW)
             */
            minLat = Math.min(minLat, content.getLatitude());
            minLng = Math.min(minLng, content.getLongitude());

            /*
             * Populating Bottom right cordinate (NE)
             */
            maxLng = Math.max(maxLng, content.getLongitude()) ;
            maxLat = Math.max(maxLat, content.getLatitude());
        }

        /*
         * Calculating Delta fit bounds
         */

        double latDelta = Math.max(Math.abs(minLat - userLocation.getLatitude()), Math.abs(maxLat-userLocation.getLatitude()));

        double lngDelta = Math.max(Math.abs(maxLng - userLocation.getLongitude()), Math.abs(minLng - userLocation.getLongitude()));

        //Calculating SW
        minLat = userLocation.getLatitude()+ latDelta;
        minLng = userLocation.getLongitude()+ lngDelta;

        latlngBounds.put("swLatLng", new GeoLocation(minLat, minLng));


        //Calculating NE
        maxLat = userLocation.getLatitude()- latDelta;
        maxLng = userLocation.getLongitude()-lngDelta;

        latlngBounds.put("neLatLng", new GeoLocation(maxLat, maxLng));

    }
```

Later in javascript i want to use as follows

```
var swLatLn = new google.maps.LatLng($!swLatLng.latitude, $!swLatLng.longitude, false);
        var neLatLn = new google.maps.LatLng($neLatLng.latitude, $neLatLng.longitude, false);

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swLatLn, neLatLn);
        googleMap.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: In what sense is it "not working"? Not compiling, giving a runtime error, giving unexpected results, or...? Is it the Java part that doesn't work or the JavaScript part? (Or both?) The JavaScript looks invalid, specifically you can't have exclamation marks in variables names like you've done with `$!swLatLng`.

Comment: $ indicates i am using velocity views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong signs (below they are corrected):

```
//Calculating SW
minLat = userLocation.getLatitude() - latDelta;
minLng = userLocation.getLongitude()- lngDelta;


//Calculating NE
maxLat = userLocation.getLatitude() + latDelta;
maxLng = userLocation.getLongitude()+ lngDelta;
```

But you definitely should tell what the problem is and whether there are error messages in the browser error console.

ps: there is an easier way for API v3
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2205577/1164491

Comment: @Faisal khan   Do you have link to the page? Or check the values of the calculated variables by yourself. Btw, look here - API 3 allows to do it automatically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556921/google-map-api-v3-set-bounds-and-center

Comment: posted stackover flow link i don't see how it is doing center with specific pins with fitbounds ?

Comment: @Faisal khan   read also this, it explains everything )
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2496558/1164491

Comment: @Faisal khan   So, you set the map center where the user is, extend bounds for all locations and call fitbounds after that.