# Google Maps: scroll map programmatically of x pixels

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, scroll, gmaps4rails

[image: scroll gmaps]

Is there a simple way to scroll a google map programmatically of `x` pixels?

I can only think of using `setCenter`, but the problem is that I would have to compute the new location (lat/lng) depending on the zoom level...

Can you think of something else? Telling me that it's not possible with the Google Map API is a valid answer if you're pretty sure about it.

ps: I'm using Gmaps4rails, so if you can think of a way to do that with the gem, it'd be cool. (like adjusting the bounds to a subset of the map.)
Because in the end my goal is to prevent the menu from hidding some markers. I would need to change the viewport of the map, if that makes sense, so that it fits the markers into the orange area, not the full map.

[image: fit markers]

---

**Solution:**

@Shane Best, great, the idea works perfectly, but I think your solution was for Google API v2, right? Here's how I did it for V3:

```
var point = map.getCenter();

var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
overlay.draw = function() {};
overlay.setMap(map);

var projection = overlay.getProjection();

var pixelpoint = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(point);
pixelpoint.x += my_value; # or .y

point = projection.fromDivPixelToLatLng(pixelpoint);

map.setCenter(point);
```

If anybody knows about a better solution with API v3, tell us about it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take a look at the projection object:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Projection

First you would need to get the center of the map.

```
var point = map.getCenter();
```

Convert the latlng to a point value.

```
var pixelpoint = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(point);
```

Add yourvalue to the point values.

```
pixelpoint.x = pixelpoint.x + yourvalue;
//or
pixelpoint.y = pixelpoint.y + yourvalue;
```

Convert it back to a latLng.

```
var newpoint = projection.fromPointToLatLng(pixelpoint);
```

Set the new center with the new value.

```
map.setCenter(newpoint);
```

I haven't tested the above but it should work.

Comment: From looking at your picture and trying to understand your problem better. You may be better off with fitbounds. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2496558/787921

Comment: Well... the bounds are defined by my markers. It's always the same for a given set of markers. What I can't manage to do, is basically modifying the viewport of the map, to exclude the top part, where the menu is, so that the fitBounds method of the map can do its job the way I want. (because I'm already using fitBounds to start with, but some markers might be hidden by the menu).

Answer (score 10):

I believe you are looking for this:

```
var panListener = google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
                    map.panBy(0,-90);
                });

setTimeout(function() {
    google.maps.event.removeListener(panListener)
}, 2000);
```

In this case, it moves the map south by 90px.