# Change annotation's position on tap of annotation

Tags: ios, google-maps, annotations, ios8

I am developing an iOS application regarding store locator. When user tap on store i need to show custom view on top of the annotation. Here my problem is annotation is always coming as center of mapview. I need to change annotation place as right corner of mapview. Any help will be appreciated

[image]

Thanks & Regards,
Sam.P

Comment: Robert,I need to move the progrmatically..I don't know how to move that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9577034/102937

Comment: Thanks Robert..My app is created with obj-C.Can you tell same solution with Obj-C.